# Exception is caused by deleting some elements of data in the second sample (sorted data) of flutter document 'PaginatedDataTable class'

Tags: flutter, dart

Exception was caused by deleting some elements of data in the second sample (sorted data) of flutter document [PaginatedDataTable class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PaginatedDataTable-class.html).

I ran the code in DartPad.

If I deleted 15 elements from `episodes` data, the exception was occurs.

The message of exception was as follows.

> Two or more TableRow children of this table had the same key.
> All the keyed TableRow children of a Table must have different Keys.

How to correct this exception?

#### Reproducible example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Flutter code sample for [PaginatedDataTable].

class MyDataSource extends DataTableSource {
  static const List<int> _displayIndexToRawIndex = <int>[0, 3, 4, 5, 6];

  late List<List<Comparable<Object>>> sortedData;
  void setData(List<List<Comparable<Object>>> rawData, int sortColumn,
      bool sortAscending) {
    sortedData = rawData.toList()
      ..sort((List<Comparable<Object>> a, List<Comparable<Object>> b) {
        final Comparable<Object> cellA = a[_displayIndexToRawIndex[sortColumn]];
        final Comparable<Object> cellB = b[_displayIndexToRawIndex[sortColumn]];
        return cellA.compareTo(cellB) * (sortAscending ? 1 : -1);
      });
    notifyListeners();
  }

  @override
  int get rowCount => sortedData.length;

  static DataCell cellFor(Object data) {
    String value;
    if (data is DateTime) {
      value =
          '${data.year}-${data.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${data.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
    } else {
      value = data.toString();
    }
    return DataCell(Text(value));
  }

  @override
  DataRow? getRow(int index) {
    return DataRow.byIndex(
      index: sortedData[index][0] as int,
      cells: <DataCell>[
        cellFor(
            'S${sortedData[index][1]}E${sortedData[index][2].toString().padLeft(2, '0')}'),
        cellFor(sortedData[index][3]),
        cellFor(sortedData[index][4]),
        cellFor(sortedData[index][5]),
        cellFor(sortedData[index][6]),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;

  @override
  int get selectedRowCount => 0;
}

void main() => runApp(const DataTableExampleApp());

class DataTableExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const DataTableExampleApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: DataTableExample(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DataTableExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const DataTableExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<DataTableExample> createState() => _DataTableExampleState();
}

class _DataTableExampleState extends State<DataTableExample> {
  final MyDataSource dataSource = MyDataSource()..setData(episodes, 0, true);

  int _columnIndex = 0;
  bool _columnAscending = true;

  void _sort(int columnIndex, bool ascending) {
    setState(() {
      _columnIndex = columnIndex;
      _columnAscending = ascending;
      dataSource.setData(episodes, _columnIndex, _columnAscending);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PaginatedDataTable(
      sortColumnIndex: _columnIndex,
      sortAscending: _columnAscending,
      columns: <DataColumn>[
        DataColumn(
          label: const Text('Episode'),
          onSort: _sort,
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: const Text('Title'),
          onSort: _sort,
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: const Text('Director'),
          onSort: _sort,
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: const Text('Writer(s)'),
          onSort: _sort,
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: const Text('Air Date'),
          onSort: _sort,
        ),
      ],
      source: dataSource,
    );
  }
}

final List<List<Comparable<Object>>> episodes = <List<Comparable<Object>>>[
  <Comparable<Object>>[
    1,
    1,
    1,
    'Strange New Worlds',
    'Akiva Goldsman',
    'Akiva Goldsman, Alex Kurtzman, Jenny Lumet',
    DateTime(2022, 5, 5),
  ],
  <Comparable<Object>>[
    2,
    1,
    2,
    'Children of the Comet',
    'Maja Vrvilo',
    'Henry Alonso Myers, Sarah Tarkoff',
    DateTime(2022, 5, 12),
  ],
  <Comparable<Object>>[
    3,
    1,
    3,
    'Ghosts of Illyria',
    'Leslie Hope',
    'Akela Cooper, Bill Wolkoff',
    DateTime(2022, 5, 19),
  ],
  <Comparable<Object>>[
    4,
    1,
    4,
    'Memento Mori',
    'Dan Liu',
    'Davy Perez, Beau DeMayo',
    DateTime(2022, 5, 26),
  ],
  <Comparable<Object>>[
    5,
    1,
    5,
    'Spock Amok',
    'Rachel Leiterman',
    'Henry Alonso Myers, Robin Wasserman',
    DateTime(2022, 6, 2),
  ],
  // Delete 15 elements here
];
```